# How can MiniProfiler display details from several levels of depth, or from ModelBinders?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

I've just integrated MiniProfiler into a product on which I've been working.

It's great, and straightforward, however there's not that much documentation that I've found for things that go beyond the most vanilla of usages.

For example, the following example code. (I know it could probably be refactored to reduce the levels of nesting, but assume that's not possible for this question)

There are 3 levels of nesting, below the overall action. From what I can tell, MiniProfiler will only display the first two levels of depth. Is this really the case, i.e. is it a feature? Or am I not using it correctly?

```
private MiniProfiler Profiler { get; set; }

public ThingController()
{
    Profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
}

public ActionResult GetPageSection(User user)
{
    List<RecordViewModel> viewModel;
    using (Profiler.Step("Get Section"))
    {
        using (Profiler.Step("Get Records from user"))
            {
                viewModel = user.Records.Where(r => r.Active).Select(
                    r =>
                        {
                            Item item
                            using (Profiler.Step("Get Item from service"))
                            {
                                item = GetItem(r);
                            }

                            using (Profiler.Step("Build record view model"))
                            {
                                return new RecordViewModel(r, item);
                            }
                        }).ToList();
            }
    }
    return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

The other issue is when trying to use the MiniProfiler from within a ModelBinder, e.g.:

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    using (Profiler.Step("Bind user"))
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

The MiniProfiler is null.

Is there any way to get the MiniProfiler to work for either of these scenarios?

Note: I'm not using MiniProfiler.MVC3. I'm just using MiniProfiler. I'm not sure if this would make a difference.

Comment: quick one, did you click show trivial?

Comment: Yep, but isn't Show Trivial only about showing existing items (within the two levels) that are really short in duration?